# how to load code using codemirror

Tags: php, jquery, load, codemirror

I have a PHP file that involved with codemirror which works great, but I want each text area to load the code from other file using PHP like `index.php`, `main.css`, `main.js`, and show preview from all of those files to combines.

My question is that how can write that code inside of each text area to link another page! I have tried to put `<?php include('css/main.css'); ?>` statement inside of one of text area for css and is not working.

Please see see full codes..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.19.0/codemirror.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<div id="wrap">

  <!-- Code Editors -->   <section id="code_editors">
    <div id="html" class="code_box">
      <h3>HTML</h3>
      <textarea name="html"></textarea>
    </div>

      <div id="css" class="code_box">
      <h3>CSS</h3>
      <textarea name="css"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div id="js" class="code_box">
      <h3>JavaScript</h3>
      <textarea name="js"></textarea>
      </div>  

      </section>

     <!-- Sandboxing -->   <section id="output">
     <iframe></iframe>   </section>    </div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.19.0/codemirror.js"></script>    
<!-- For HTML/XML --> <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.19.0/mode/xml/xml.js">/script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.19.0/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>    
<!-- For CSS --> <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.16.0/mode/css/css.js"></script>    
<!-- For JS --> <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.19.0/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script> <script src="js/js.js"></script>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is trying to include the css file contents without `link` tag. Replace `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">` instead of `<?php include('css/main.css'); ?>`.

Comment: it does not work that way either by put link tag. i also see in.js file showing code // SETTING CODE EDITORS INITIAL CONTENT
 html_editor.setValue('<p>Hello World</p>');
 css_editor.setValue('body { color: red; }'); and i have no idea how to repalce with file path name, i have tried everything i could .. any other idea!